# How to get page source code using JRex?

Tags: java

How to access page source code using [JRex](http://jrex.mozdev.org/)?

Comment: Sure I will go and accept all the answers just because they are there - so stupid of me because I fought I should accept only those which are CORRECT...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//WebNavigation navigation = null;
//URI uri = null;

navigation.loadURI(uri, WebNavigationConstants.LOAD_FLAGS_NONE, null, null, null);
Document doc = navigation.getDocument();
Element ex = doc.getDocumentElement();
System.out.println(ex.getTextContent()); //prints page source
```